# Asp.Net mvc 4 with jQuery partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with jQuery in a Asp.Net MVC 4 project.

I have an Index with a table in a "content" div and other "content2" div to show partial views.

When the user click on any item of the list, the Detail partial view is showed correctly in "content2".
That Detail view has an Edit actionlink to call the controller that load your view in the same div ("content2").

When the Edit ended I refresh the list without problem in "content".

At this point is all working good.

I need that the "content2" div show again the original Detail, I mean the Detail that was called and edited.

I hope you can understand me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reload the page, optionally with an id to determine what partial view should be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the id of that item which was being edited as routevalues in your return statement like below
    return RedirectToAction("ActionMethod", new { ItemID = value });
If you want to know more about Routing in ASP.Net MVC the link is given below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx